# Multiple Users in JMeter Resulting in an Error

Tags: jmeter, authorization

Currently all the JMeter scripts I have written never have any errors when I run them with one user. When I add more however (ie 5), then one or two will end up giving me the 401 Authorization Required message. I have two reg-ex extractors capturing the X-CSRF currently and I use those values in the HTTP Header Manager. I'm not getting why I only get an error part time (I know it's not because of my User Parameters because when I run the different users one user at a time they work). Is it something that doesn't work with the website I'm testing? Or JMeter? Or have I missed something?

Comment: can you show your test plan ? and detail how you extract tokens and inject them ? thx

Comment: I used a recording controller to login -> add internal review -> logout. I added a regex extractor to a "handshake" step that requires a X-CSRF. The regular expression is X-CSRF : (.+)? Variable Name: token Template: $1$ Match No. 1 and Field to Check is Response Headers. I then replace X-CSRF in HTTP Header Manager connected to the step after the "handshake" step with ${token}.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your extractors are failing to extract the tokens.

I suggest that you use gui to debug:

- add a View Results Tree and run your test.
- add a debug post processor under Test Plan
- run your test

See what you extracted. Then use in View Results Tree response tab the Regexp Tester to see if your regexp match responses and extract tokens correctly.

Comment: My token is extracted properly probably 3-4 times out of 5. When it doesn't work, it doesn't extract anything and uses the default value of Not Found.

Comment: Isn't this your issue ? Can you show your test plan ? Thank you

Comment: I have a thread group and under it, User Parameters, HTTP Cokkie Manager, HTTP Cache Manager and a recording controller. In the Recording controller I have an HTTP request for the login page, one for the Handshake step, one to Login, and then I have several other HTTP Requests to perform the actual script: which is adding an internal review to a website. Each HTTP request has its own header manager and the handshake step and the login step each have a regex token.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check following:

1. Is your token being extracted properly? - You can add debug sampler at the end of the test. This will show you values picked by different users. Just run one iteration for easy debugging.
2. Have you added cookie manager? Check if you are clearing cookies after every iteration?
3. Have you added cache manager? Check if you are clearing cache.
4. Do you have a global header manager or header for each request separately? If you are using default header manager, that could cause this issue.

Comment: I have a separate header for each request, a cache manager and a cookie manager that are both clearing, and my token is extracted probably 3-4 times out of 5. When it doesn't work, it uses the default value of Not Found. I do have two regex tokens though, and it's the second one, the one being picked up on the first page where I get a 401 error, that is the one that is problematic.

Comment: Can you share the details of response you are receiving and regex you are using to extract? That help me understand the problem better.

Comment: On the Regex extractor page in GUI, I have main sample and sub-samples chosen, response headers chosen as field to check. Reference name is Token, the regex is X-CSRF: (.+)? the template is $1$ match no. is 1 and default value is Not found. When I run with five users in one thread group, the third and fifth users don't work (displaying a 401 Authorization required message) at and after the step with the token. When you run it again different users won't work (first and fourth). Sometimes the whole thing works.

Comment: In case where the token is not extracted, do you see proper response for previous request? Check view results tree and I would suggest add response assertion to validate the response which generates X-CSRF token. Can you share sample X-CSRF token as well. I want to validate regex.

Comment: A sample X-CSRF token would be : PMbq6c3iV6KWX1IVUKsutL2A/JI+5YtbCNQchw8nYUg=

Comment: @Elizabeth I meant the sample response. I want left and right boundaries. Can you share something like X-CSRF: PMbq6c3iV6KWX1IVUKsutL2A/JI+5YtbCNQchw8nYUg= – . Also try one test with a tweak. Add some delay between two requests say 5 seconds and run the test. Just want to check something.

Comment: I put a constant timer under the second HTTP request (aka Handshake step) and while it worked the first time, I tried it two more times and users 3 and 4 didn't work first then 2, 3, and 4 didn't work.

Comment: I am a bit confused by response assertion. I put X_CSRF: (.+)? under the step that failed but it didn't come up with anything. I tried putting it under the step before but it also said Test failed: headers expected to contain /X-CSRF: (.+)?/

Comment: @Elizabeth Can I see the test plan? Or sample request/response? You need to put response assertion on the same step where you get X-CSRF token.